# Recessed lighting malfunctioning

Tags: recessed-lighting

My home is 1.5 years old.  After a thunder storm, 9 of 13 recessed lights are not functioning properly.  3 are out completely.  The others continue to dim until barely lit.  They are in 4 different rooms.  None are on dimmers.  The television & a remote on my recliner were also blown; which I have replaced.  Please help

Comment: Have you tried replacing the bulbs in the fixtures not working?

Comment: They are hard wired & appears that the entire unit must be replaced?

Comment: Sounds like lighting caused a power surge in your wires.  Guessing problem lights are LEDs or CFLs and same happen to them as your TV.  Will need replacement.  If thunder storms are common in your area suggest whole house power surge protector or at least surge protectors(not power bars) for electronic equipment(TVs, computers)

Comment: I agree with crip659 the driver circuit was probably damaged with the same power surge that damaged the TV & recliner you might have insurance coverage I would check. The only way to reduce the possibility of this happening again would be to install a whole house surge protector.

Comment: ...and whole house surge protectors have become common and inexpensive, since they are required under new codes, so more get made and the volume brings the prices down.

Comment: Wondering if anything else is damaged, being a newer house would think most major appliances will have mainly electronics controlling them and damage not noticed yet.

Comment: Agree with other's comments here, the LED drivers probably all blew out.  I had a major power surge at my cabin and found that EVERY GFCI outlet was fried and half the breakers were tripped in the main panel. I don't have a whole house protector, but even though we seldom have serious lightning storms here, I'm seriously considering installing one.

Answer (score 3):

### They need replacing

From the sounds of things, these are LED recessed fixtures with integral drivers.  Unfortunately, that means that if a power surge kills them, its off to get them replaced, unless somebody around's up for light fixture surgery that is.  The good news is that it's not terribly hard to find replacement fixtures as recessed lights have settled on a few "de facto" standard sizes for some time now.